# Is possible to read the pattern regex from property file?

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation

Is possible to read the regexp from property file?

```
@Pattern(regexp = "{A-Za-z0-9}*")

private String name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Bean Validation reference implementation Hibernate Validator, you could declare the constraint programmatically using the [API for constraint declaration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api). You'd have to read the regular expression from the property file yourself and then pass it when configuring the constraint via the API.